# save values from strigng array in 2d int array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been taking a voluntary computer science course at school share for 1 month and want to practice something. Task:

I am to store a series of numbers with symbols in a string array for the first time. The numbers are to be stored in a two-dimensional int array. But the symbols should look different on output. And the output should be done only using the values of the int array. The numbers are one-digit. There is no need to check if the user makes the input correctly.

This is how the program should look like when it is executed:

```
Input:
.1.2.3.|.4.5.6.|.7.8.9 
-------|-------|------- 

Output:
;1;2;3;//;4;5;6;//;7;8;9 
=======//=======//=======
```

I know that you always have to proceed in small steps. I have made it so far that the input is output exactly the same again. I just can't get the solution, I have been sitting here for hours. How do I save the numbers I have saved to the string array to the 2d array? And how do I replace the symbols to look like the example?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
 
    int ArrayTwo[3][2] = {0}; //From Task
    string ArrayInput[2] = {""}; //From Task
 
    cout << "Input:" << endl;
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cin >> ArrayInput[i];
    }
 
    cout << "Output" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cout << ArrayInput[i] << endl;
    }
 
 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a neat trick you can pull with `std::stringstream` and `std::getilne`you read a line from the file. You put the line in the `istringstream`, and then you use `getline's third parameter to specify what you want to use as the separator and pull the string apart. For example, `std::istringstream strm(line); std::string token; while (std::getline(strm,  token, `|`)) { std::cout << token<< ' '; }`. For the first line this will print `.1.2.3. .4.5.6. .7.8.9 `. Then you can do the same thing with the '.' in place of '\' and get `1 2 3`.

Comment: This leads to a really cool idea: Why not replace all of the '|'s, '-'s, and '.'s in the string with spaces? Then you could use `>>` to read all of the integers. See [`std::replace_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) for a tool that does just that.

Comment: @user4581301 I am not allowed to use stringstream but thank you

Comment: Given this description I'd have expected the type of `ArrayTwo` to be `int[3][3]` and not `int[9][2]`. Where do the other 9 numbers come from?

Comment: Rats. Are you allowed to use the `find` function or `std::string`'s `find` method?

Comment: @user4581301 unfortunately also not :(

Comment: That leaves brute force and ignorance. Do what you would do if you had a pen, paper, and someone calling inputs out at you. Look at the string character by character. If you find a digit, keep it. Any other character discard it. Maybe you need to assemble the digits into larger numbers. In that case once you find a digit, multiply what you have collected by ten and add the new digit until you find something that's not a digit. Store the number you've collected, set the collector back to zero and look for the next digit.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for your suggestion, but I don't think I can solve this problem. I just give up.  I can't do it with my programming skills

Comment: You can. Sometimes you can't come up with a good computer way, so you do it the human way. That gives you something that works. It may not work efficiently, but it works and you can build on it. convert the line into numbers step by step the way you would do it by hand.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you, but I have no idea how :(

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's simplest to iterate to simply iterate through the input string and convert anything that's a digit to a number:

```
#include <cctype>
...

void PrintInner(int (&inner)[3])
{
    std::cout << ';';
    for (auto element : inner)
    {
        std::cout << element << ';';
    }
}

...

int ArrayTwo[3][3];
string ArrayInput[2];

...

auto readPos = ArrayInput[0].cbegin();

for (auto& inner : ArrayTwo)
{
    for(auto& element : inner)
    {
        // skip non-digit chars
        while(!std::isdigit(*readPos))
        {
            ++readPos;
        }
        element = *readPos - '0'; // char codes of digits 0123456789 are next to each other
        ++readPos;
    }
}

cout << "Output" << endl;

PrintInner(ArrayTwo[0]);


for (int i = 1; i != 3; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "//";
    PrintInner(ArrayTwo[i]);
}
...
```

[Demo on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAJwAbKSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIADM/qQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BAcEZWY4C4ZExLPGJKbaY9qUMQgRMxAR5Pn5BdQ05za0E5dFxCcmpCi1tHQXdEwNDldVjAJS2qF7EyOwc5kkRyN5YANQmSW7IDgCeaZin2CYaAIK7%2B4eYJ2dOE8SYrHcPzzMewYBy8x1Obm%2BEWA/yeXiyRiOzDYCjSTC2Rwm6FOVieAIAbqg8OgjspiBECABJBiRYgQClHCDmQIRWnLEwAVgsSU5ABF2XiAOy4x5HMWYgjoEAodYED5uCFHMA7JIWZU4gHio78YiMpheIhHeqYNiCI4gI6shIC0XikzCzVa8VY6VoA3yxXG01yiGK9Wq/0irX23kAkNhp4MlhMCIQG32oOOsUMx7EYhMS4AFQA7qhOdy%2BfmeRzeR9SwmNOHVUcAPQ1gBixFQLCOmaYCgA1kmJeTEan05dqWkDfmzHyyycHWYx9OqxZaw2my2253Nd23T6zorzGYhwaQDuPWcjQx0LQNU8TpfxTrGQy8BPK9WH4qx8/rNYbcGHdenUdkBEHz3Ek2BHP2GZ7gQ%2BZ4IWqrduGeK/kc%2BqGj8TDoMomQTuBg4MMOUFcpWJYAHTIPEwCxuycGIbaYq3hAKF5mYgSWjSCTmmBaYZjmqBfnaP60U6OoMQaTEsV6jByhaVrEHxf4Jt2f5inWmIdngaRIgIAC0%2BAUXKyAIK0CiKUp2YIHQmAQGAYAuiAeAKLphAQAAVGhGGZMsclKWKClId5waWNYbmYcZ1GCd5CHhUpElmqcpaub87kKEcWlKhwGiBgu/6GbqaBYMlqBUEcjkEMlGhcECkgcoEgoABz%2BMhPxIpgqhyoavwGUcqAEAgCQmfJgWWMFmQXlFPmCqGSGReuspHm4JzTgA8ga%2BGHr6x6uOeYXdmSFLUrSEA4Tx%2BZEfyo3BlNSH0feE5cDilpKmAcVHDy1YfpYeBeb5Y0SlKMruut807nWO7nUpu2CPtCSHVxWa5tBfJUUG/GTaK3Y/AQGwMEcT4iiGHCrLQnAcrwfjpbwqCcAqg3zgo6ybO8uw8KQBCaATqwdiAHKSMRSQaLVGj%2BCk/iSIKdUaIKwRExwkik2zpCUxwvAKCAGgs2zqxwLASAtZgyCiWQFAMcQwAKMohj1EICCoNmZPM2gLBpHQTCNObkS0FbNtk1opAO079CJAchjAFwHIaGrfsWcQy3CNbtvy7ryCpqbnC8InzT4GTxFcMRZi88R9puMRPMcsRgQF4KReCsRtXEQ1AJaY3TdaYXzdN63bdabw/CCCIYjsFIMiCIoKjqOTpC6Fw%2BjByg702LQeCxCrkCrKgaSNCrHBaYtZgpVicWmDTXCCsr9NbHoWIRG7ltx97vAED82zM9m6ZpBr%2BjE3L4%2BK9gqh6wbRxVC1UCFpQIkh/wGERKHYiGgYGMmplYSwpAji4EICQBaSQuDLHvhrVYvV0KjDjKQTmVUy7%2BC4P4DQgRw4cmnBQsw0hpay1ICwCQ4dSB3wVqnWwqt1bk08h/DgZgv4%2B0Vjg/hqx8QJCyM4SQQA%3D%3D)

In case you're unfamiliar with this: `for ( ... : ...)` is a [ranged for-loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for); this sets the loop variable to the elements of the array in increasing order of indices.

Comment: thank you very much, but things like .cbegin(), for (auto element : inner), auto, while(!std::isdigit(*readPos)), !=, we didn't have unfortunately. How to write these in a different way?

Comment: @NewMan `readPos` is an iterator here, i.e. an object that stores the info about the position of a character, `*readPos` provides access to the character and `++readPos` moves one to the right to the next char, so you could replace declare an index variable initialized with 0 instead, replace `++readPos` with incrementing the index variable and `*readPos` with passing the index variable to the `[]` operator of the string. `for (type varName : container) { ... }` can be replaced with `for (size_t index = 0; index != std::size(container); ++index) { type varName = container[index]; ... }`

Comment: Don't forget that the `&` is part of the type when converting the ranged for-loops. Also checking, if a `char c` is a digit can be done via `(c >= '0') && (c <= '9')`

Comment: thank you very much but i dont get it. I dont now how to write it in a different way. And can I remove cctype? Its not allowed unfortunately

Comment: @NewMan `#include <cctype>` is needed for `std::isdigit` only and isn't needed, if you use the check mentioned in the previous comment. `for (auto& inner : ArrayTwo) { for(auto& element : inner) { ... } }` can be rewritten as `for (size_t i = 0; i != 3; ++i) { int (&inner)[3] = ArrayTwo[i]; for(size_t j = 0; j != 3; ++j) { int& element = inner[j]; ... } }`